# ERROR: ERROR_MR_FEX_NOT_FOUND Can't create item object based on provided item key FRCSTDAT.fex

Tags: webfocus

Can any one please tell me why I am getting the following error when I am running the focexec in managed reporting (WebFocus)?

> ERROR: ERROR_MR_FEX_NOT_FOUND Can't create item object based on provided item key FRCSTDAT.fex

I am using main focexec as "VOINVDAT" AND INLUDING "FRCSTDAT" as INCLUDE file in the main focexec.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your WebFocus environment isn't able to find a specific .fex file it needs, or a table relationship you have is bad.  Might check key names and relationships as well as files present.

Answer (score 0):

The include should have the path if the .fex is not in the default search path.

Answer (score 0):

From MR Section, to include any fex file from Reporting Server location, you need to include like:

```
-MRNOEDIT -INCLUDE fex_file_name.fex
```

Note the fex_file_name.fex should be in Reporting Server location. Let me know if this works for your problem.